# How to finalize a game to be able to start another one?

Tags: java, swing

I am doing a game with Swing.

It starts with a `main` method that waits with a `while(true)` for every time the user wants to start a new game.

For restarting the game, I have a menu that allows you to return to the main menu and start another game. The problem is that the last game is not finished and the `while(true)` of the `main` method that attends petitions is stuck in the function that executes the game.

If I FINISH the last game playing normally, then the function ends, and the `while(true)` of the `main` method is ready to attends more new games.

How can I force the last game to end?

Comment: Your game logic should be ultimately encapsulated by some instantiated class. Then, when you want to end the game, you can discard the instantiation, and to start the game create a new instantiation.

Comment: "How can I force the last game to end?" well you need 1.2 GigaWatts... well i guess that depends on your code, which we don't have. see the problem? please don't use `while(true) {`

Comment: Are you asking how to force the program to terminate or..?

Answer (score 2):

Use `break` to exit from the `while(true)` loop.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Choose a game mode 1-start normal, 2-start hard, 3-exit");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("3")) {
       break;
    } else if (input.equals("2")) {
       startGameInHard();
    } // else if ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be not to have `while(true)`, instead have `while(condition)` where condition could be your functional logic:

```
while(!gameRestarted || lastGameFinished)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swing is an IoC (Inversion of Control) framework, which means you should let your `main` return after creating your main window.

If you need a thread to run while a game is active you should start a new `Thread` when the user starts a game.

If the user interrupts a game by starting a new before the current one has finished normally you need to tell the current game that it should finish and then you simply spawn a new thread for the new game.